# Jssor dynamic thumbnail not working

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, instagram, jssor

I am trying to make a jssor gallery based of instagram feed. So far the images are succeeding, but not the thumbnails.

```
var img = '<img u="image" src="'+thisMedia.images.standard_resolution.url+'" alt="Instagram Image" data-filter="'+thisMedia.filter+'" width="720" height="480" />';
var thumb = '<img u="thumb" src="'+thisMedia.images.standard_resolution.url+'" width="99" height="66"/>';

$('#slide-'+i+'').html(img);
$('#slide-'+i+'').append(thumb);
```

This happens in the instafeed file and so far the img goes well in the gallery but not the thumb. Ive also tried to put the thumb code in the same line for the img variable.

When I open it in the browser and check what is happening i see the images and thumbnails correctly being put in the desired div slides. Allthough the thumbnails should be taken care of by the jssor code they just sit there, I basically copied the code of the demo version. Any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

In the raw html, thumbnail for a slide is defined in following format.

```
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../img/alila/01.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="../img/alila/thumb-01.jpg" />
        </div>
```

When jssor slider initializes, it hide the thumbnail in the slide and copy a clone to thumbnail navigator. Actually, thumbnail navigator is a kind of slider.

You can inspect element to see how it arranges. If you need to replace thumbnails, please operate elements in thumbnail navigator.

Comment: So this basically means I can only dynamically load the image src when the thumb img is set beforehand and not the whole img tag?

Comment: For now, there is no api to do this job easily. What you are doing is workaround, you can reach the goal in this way, but it is a bit complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the support! Great job on the library :)