# jssor: loading a dynamic menu is not getting attached

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I am loading from database the menu dynamic however the attachement to the menu happens just after the jssor is loaded, so is not getting attached.

I am using a webservice to retrieve the data, so data shows up after the binding.
Found this article ([Jssor dynamic thumbnail not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25406421/jssor-dynamic-thumbnail-not-working)) but not really helping out.
Any help would be appriciated as I cant handle static menus

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, need to place the jssor caller in the loader from the ws